# Best Redis maxmemory configuration for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, redis

Right now i'm using Redis as my Magento 2 full page cache and session cache, but sometime this cause my website to get out of memory error, i've fixed the `memory_limit` for the php and i found out my `maxmemory` is set to 0 which is unlimited, this can be the source of the problem, what is the best `maxmmemory` config for Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links can Help,

- > [What is minimum / recommended RAM size for Redis when used as Magento Cache?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215947/what-is-minimum-recommended-ram-size-for-redis-when-used-as-magento-cache/291144#291144)
- > [Redis cache getting full](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350298/redis-cache-getting-full/350304#350304)

---

**Thank You!**