# Magento 2.4.3p1 - Redis keeps growing

Tags: magento2.4, redis, docker, memory, magento2.4.3.p1

So, we went live with a new m2 shop last week. It all worked well in our develop environment. Since we dockerized the m2 installation, I wasnt expecting much trouble. But our redis cache keeps growing (pretty fast: about 3MB/s).
I have a small workaround in place, so the server does not run out of memory. I set the maxmemory to 4GB in a cronjob (every 5 minutes), because even with the limit and memory-policy in place, the redis container crashes from time to time. It also restarts, but then the cronjob needs to set the values again.

I know, there was a problem in 2.4.2 with the CSP module (see [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25487)), but I disabled the CSP Module and we are running 2.4.3.

Also I found [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350298/redis-cache-getting-full), but it wast really helpfull.

Is anyone else experiencing this behaviour?
Oh, and for the record: I have tested redis 6.0 and 6.2 - but the behaviour stays the same. The server has 16GB of memory in total.

Comment: Have you considered trying to run without Redis?

Comment: You may find this URL helpful.  https://www.lexiconn.com/blog/2017/11/redis-and-magento-more-than-meets-the-eye/     We provide MySQL and MariaDB performance tuning services which could simplify your life.  View profile for contact info and free Utility Scripts, please.

Comment: Without redis, the storage gets full after some time - so, the problem stays the same. It seems, it is a known bug in 2.4.3 and should get fixed in 2.4.4.
For now, as our environment is running in docker containers, I restrained the redis containers use of RAM and set  maxmemory to 4GB and maxmemory-policy to allkeys-lru

Comment: Has anyone reviewed your code responsible for 'Connect', 'Process', 'Close' connection?  Sounds like CLOSE has been missed.

Comment: I am not using any self-written code to connect to redis.
I might face this issue:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9458
It should be fixed with 2.4.4 (but I have not tried yet)